How do I learn more about rocketry?
I've always been inclined to rocketry from a young age. I've done several projects on it and a lot of research. Now, with the help of a friend, I've also found this place of smart beings. I'm just curious how I can learn more. What are some good sources for learning concepts of propulsion and aerodynamics? Understanding how one eventually gets into rocketry as one progresses in life. What is the process of eventually becoming an aerospace engineer?
How does one get into NASA or other space agencies?

When I worked at JSC pretty much the only way to get hired at NASA as a college grad was to have been a NASA intern/co-op while you were in college. No idea if that's still the case, but I'd look into it.

@OrganicMarble for a fresh-out, being an intern is still the best way. It's gotten much easier to move into civil service from contract in the last decade or so

You can learn an awful lot by doing. This doesn't mean that you should run out and mix up a bunch of dangerous chemicals, but rather try to do something in a virtual environment at first, and then if it's not dangerous, get your hands dirty and build something novel in real life. If it results in a story that you tell passionately and where you say "I" a lot, this experience will probably lead you into the career you want.

KSP with realism mods, model rocketry, model rocket design, etc etc etc

@phil1008 I've made several Solid Rocket Motors since I was 11 (Currently I'm 14) and have used several programs such as F3D and Open Rocket. I also worked on several avionics factors and tried to make a model rocket (With avionics and parachutes using a completely self-built motor) but realized I have no safe launching space near where I live. So do you think this may help?

@Aerospace_Nerd You're building a story about how you made something that can be easily bought. It may be fun, but it doesn't sound novel enough to set you apart as an innovator. Your idea has to be really novel and compelling - if you were into botany it would be something like inventing grass that turns blue when exposed to chemicals leeched from old landmines.

I understand your point, sooner or later, I'll bring something innovative to the table.

You've asked several excellent questions, each of which could be explored in detail. To provide a clearer overview, I'll divide them into two parts: A) Where can I learn more about rocketry and B) How can I pursue a career in the aerospace industry?
Question A: Where can I learn more about rocketry
If you're starting from the basics, it's important to first build a strong foundation in space exploration, physics, and mathematics before diving into more complex topics. Space is, after all, a challenging domain.
One great place to get a practical understanding of orbital mechanics is through the game Kerbal space program. It's probably one of the best simulators for learning about space exploration, but remember, it's still just a game and not a perfect representation of real life physics. For instance, KSP uses a simplified conical system, so things like Lagrange points are not represented.
While KSP is great for understanding some basics, it oversimplifies many aspects of rocketry, such as rocket engines, heat shields, reaction wheels, etc.. Fortunately, many other people have covered those topics such as Scott Manley in his playlist of things KSP doesn't teach or the Everyday astronaut who gave a deep dive into rocket engines (Unfortunately, I couldn't find a playlist, but I think that these particular videos are some of his most informative ones 1, 2, 3).
There are other great sources to learn more in depth about rocket engines, but many of those have been covered already in other answers such as Which are good resources to learn more about the components of a rocket engine? and Resources and references on the topic of space exploration
Question B: How can I pursue a career in the aerospace industry
The aerospace industry can be challenging to break into, but there are several pathways. Such as earning a relevant degree and logging thousands of hours flying a fighter jet is one route to becoming an astronaut. It's important to remember that the aerospace industry encompasses a wide range of roles, from scientists and engineers in R&D or rocket-building facilities to professionals in finance and politics. Getting as much relevant experience as possibly is crucial to standing and increasing your chances of entering the industry. I will explain what I recommend, but of course take it with a grain of salt, since everybody can take their own way.
To start, identify your strengths and interests. Are you good at programming? Do you enjoy hands-on work? Consider making a list of your skills. Once you have a better understanding of your abilities, you should try to find local groups, such as university organisations, student groups or volunteer associations, that are working on related projects. This doesn’t necessarily have to be in aerospace; any technical experience is valuable. The main point being that you turned up there and actually went on your own terms to go and get experience.
With some basic experience under your belt, you can start applying for internships. The company size really matters, since if you apply somewhere where there is a lot of competition, then you will be rejected and if the company is too small, it will be seen as too much effort to host an intern. Therefore I recommend applying to a mid-sized company between 50 to 500 employees. If a company doesn’t explicitly state that they’re looking for interns, consider reaching out anyway, but make sure to highlight what you have to offer. Think about it like this, there is a small group that you go to, nobody was expecting you there, if you show that you can perform well, you get the gig. This approach can make it easier for the company to see the value in bringing you on as an intern. At this stage, I recommend using LinkedIn to find suitable companies.
While pursuing your degree, it’s a good idea to aim for a master's in an aerospace-related subject. Although some positions in the industry require only a bachelor’s degree, most roles prefer at least a master’s. You should try to get a few internships during your study time- ideally even before starting university. By the time you graduate, you'll not only have a degree, but also experience from a few companies. When applying for jobs in the aerospace industry, you should prioritise jobs that you want to do, over a higher salary. While it may not seem that tempting to go for a lower salary job, getting in is the golden ticket to moving towards your goals.
From this point on, your path will depend on your specific goal. If you want to become an astronaut and apply to do so, don't be surprised to be rejected. Many astronauts have to apply multiple times before being accepted. There's even a famous story of an astronaut applying 14 times before being accepted. NASA wants to see dedications, so rejections as expected, but never give up. If flying to space is your dream, then you better work hard towards it.

You have some really specific points in Part B, like using LinkedIn specifically or proceeding to a Master's degree instead of a Bachelor's. What do you base those on?

Kerbal Space Program can easily "level up" to a greater degree of realism with mods like Realism Overhaul and RP-0 -- same caveats that it's only a game, but you can get a lot closer to realistic sim.

More important probably for a potential aerospace engineer than becoming a KSP orbital mechanics expert or a seasoned watcher of Scott Manley videos is to get a good grasp of the fundamentals: physics, thermodynamics, the math etc. The unflashy but critical stuff that engineering starts with. Don't try to get too specialized too early. You don't know what will be in demand when you graduate. My computer classes ended up being a lot more valuable to my path than three semesters of aerodynamics.

Its also probably important to note that very few people are capable of becoming astronauts. 100's if not 1000's apply and usually only 10 or 20 get the job, and possibly even fewer ever actually pass the Karman Line in their lifetime.

Supplementary answer:
Review the following in Space Exploration Meta:

Community Policy Repository (scroll down to "Resources")
Educational resources to accompany Space Exploration
Resources and references on the topic of space exploration


Getting into NASA or a similar space agency is like launching a payload into orbit — requires precision, timing, and lots of preparation. Gain experience in the aerospace industry, ideally working on space-related projects. NASA looks for people with a proven track record of innovation and expertise. Connect with professionals in the field. Attend aerospace conferences, join professional organizations and keep an eye out for networking opportunities.

According to Eric Berger's inspiring Liftoff, SpaceX had a pattern of hiring cheap but sharp engineering rookies who stand out from the crowd.
It is advantageous to not have a family, be somewhere on the spectrum (so you can deal with Elon) and be able and willing to work 100 hours a week while being underpaid. (I'm hardly joking.)
On the upside, you participate in making history and shape things at a speed and to a degree that is unheard off in more traditional aerospace companies (all three or four of them ;-) ).
It seems to help if one stands out, sometimes simply by being persistent to the point of being obnoxious, and if one is able to answer hard questions in interviews.
Of course, the stories this post is based on are now 10-15 years old; but I think Musk's preference of young, excitable and exploitable engineers is unbroken.
